# grails install-plugin does not work for me

Tags: grails

I received a very odd error when I run 'grails install spring-security-core 1.2.4'in my window's command line

```
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;1.2.4: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_4/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.4.zip

```
    Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_4/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.4.zip
```

Error resolving plugin [name:spring-security-core, group:org.grails.plugins, version:1.2.4].
Plugin not found for name [spring-security-core] and version [1.2.4]

Strangely I can download the zip file by providing the url (http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_4/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.4.zip) in my browser.

Anybody experienced same issue?

If I omit the version number in the command line, I see the url string is totally wrong:

> ```
>   ==== grailsCentral: tried
> ```

```
    -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

    http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-spring-security-core-[revision].zip

  ==== grailsCore: tried

    -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

    http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-spring-security-core-[revision].zip

          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

          :: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration: not found

          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

By the way, I am using Grails 1.3.7. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Just a small tip but you can also install plugin from a zip file from your local file system ... since you already have it.

```
grails install-plugin ../my-plugin-0.1.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into your project's BuildConfig.groovy

```
/[Your_Project_Name]/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
```

Find the repositiories section:

repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

```
// uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
// from public Maven repositories
//mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
//mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
//mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
//mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
//mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
```

}

Search for `mavenCentral()`.
Uncomment this line out.  This will then enable remote dependency resolution.

Then try the `install-plugin` command on the command line.

Here is an example:

```
install-plugin mail
```

or

```
install-plugin http://plugins.grails.org/grails-mail/tags/RELEASE_1_0-SNAPSHOT/grails-mail-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

If running install-plugin on the command line does not work for you, you can try the plugin manager.

*Right-click your project -> Grails Tools(Towards the bottom) -> Grails Plugin Manager.*

Search for your plugin then install and click the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

If You have to use Proxy to connect to the Internet, try this:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html