# Plugin spring-security-core-2.0-RC4 requires version 2.3.0 of Grails. but in fact i am using "spring-security-core=1.1.2"

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Recently i have changed my system os to windows 10(32 bit). before i was using windows 7 and windows xp on those os it was working, but now after changing os it is giving error Plugin spring-security-core-2.0-RC4 requires version [2.3.0 > *] 
of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet.
Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails. (grails-1.3.7 and jdk1.6.0_22) which are same when i am working on windows 7(64bit) and xp(32bit).

**update:** now i am getting error "module not found: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: it is not clear what you ask - The error says you need a higher version of Grails and you don't have that.

Comment: @chris-sc it is as simple as i asked. i mentioned the error which is saying spring-security-core-2.0.RC4 requires version > 2.3.0 but i am not using mentioned version of spring security plugins in fact i am using spring-security-core 1.1.2 then why i am getting this error.

Comment: It says it requires version >2.3.0 of Grails, but you are using grails 1.3.7.

Comment: @chris-sc but i can't upgrade it to 2.3.0 its too old project. any workaround thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BuildConfig.groovy
uncomment   **mavenCentral()**

Then try the install-plugin command on the command line or in sts ctrl+shift+alt g

Here is an example:

```
grails install-plugin http://plugins.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_0_1/grails-spring-security-core-1.1.2.zip
```

If running install-plugin on the command line does not work for you, you can try the plugin manager.

Right-click your project -> Grails Tools(Towards the bottom) -> Grails Plugin Manager.

Search for your plugin then install and click the OK button.

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905714/grails-install-plugin-does-not-work-for-me). I could have given link directly but I don't want you to lead any confusion. above is worked for me.