# how to build an old grails project

Tags: grails-2.0

trying to build an old grails 2.0.0 project, it seems that it can't properly resolve all dependencies. I guess this is because it looks for them at svn.codehaus...

How to I have to update my dependencies to build the project again?

Comment: Maybe the answers in [grails install-plugin does not work for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905714/grails-install-plugin-does-not-work-for-me) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded by upgrading my project to Grails 2.0.4 - silly me, I should have done this first...